# Refresh token in Passport.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js

How do I do this in Passport.js?:

> When the access token expires, you can use the refresh_token to
>   "refresh" your access, and gain another access_token. To use the
>   refresh_token you need to do a POST request to our token-endpoint with
>   the grant_type set to refresh_token:

```
https://podio.com/oauth/token?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I asked Jared if he would consider adding something into the core to make this a little easier to handle. He responded by saying that this should not be handled in the core.

So I wrote a plugin to help: https://github.com/fiznool/passport-oauth2-refresh

Answer (score 12):

answer from **Jared Hanson**, author *PassportJS*:

> Refresh tokens are something handled entirely on the backend, and not
>   connected to a user's session.  For example: set up a cron job, query
>   for tokens about to expire, make POST requests to refresh them.
>
> Passport doesn't get involved in this process, because its separate
>   from authentication.